# php for changing images

Tags: php, javascript, html

I just want to ask if possible to call an image using php? For example I have homepage that has 1 div for image (pic1) then after two weeks I will change the image into (pic2). How can I accomplish it without going to my cpanel to change the code . Are there any program or languages that can help me to do that? I am trying to do the back-end side of my homepage to change the images.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You'll have to post a great deal more detail about your site and how you want to change your images to get a more helpful answer.

Comment: And after 4 weeks `pic3`? What is the source of the images? Is there a list?

Comment: Hi my source code for my image is this 
<div id="image"><img src="images/pic1"></div>
this is my default image location. What I want is to  change it without doing anything to my hmtl code. with the help of php or any other program is it possible to create a back-end just for changing the image? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

You can use PHP's `date()` function in combination with an if/else statement to determine what picture to use.

Example:

```
if(date('d-m-y') == 'yourdate'){
    //Show picture 1
}
```

Next to that, with a little searching you could've figured this out on your own perfectly fine ;)

Comment: Good answer as well! :)

Comment: hi there! thank you I am trying to build a back end for the changing images only. at first I'm thinking I will going to change the html souce code manually my default code is 
<div id="image"><img src="images/pic1"></div>, then after two weeks I will change the code to this <div id="image"><img src="images/pic2"></div>. But I felt this is too much work to upload in my cpanel everytime I change my image. Is there a way to automate it using other program?

Answer (score 2):

Changing images is very simple. If you want to do it automatically, you could setup a CRON job or use PHP's date function. If you want to do it manually, by selecting a button, you can do it like this:

```
<script>
  function changeSrc() {
   document.getElementById("myImage").src="imageName.jpg";
  }
</script>
<body>
  <img id="myImage" src="otherImage.jpg" width="107" height="98">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="changeSrc()" value="Change image">
</body>
```

Comment: Hi anthony thank you I will try this code. at first I'm thinking I will going to change the html souce code manually my default code is <div id="image"><img src="images/pic1"></div>, then after two weeks I will change the code to this <div id="image"><img src="images/pic2"></div>. But I felt this is too much work to upload in my cpanel everytime I change my image.